# How to get next week start and end date in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have try to get next week start and end date but I have got current week start and end date.How can get next week start and end date in Objective-c.

Comment: show what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all dates of this week and next week using following code:-

```
NSArray * allDatesOfThisWeek = [self daysThisWeek];
NSArray * allDatesOfNextWeek = [self daysNextWeek];
```

Following methods are used for calculating dates of this week:-

```
-(NSArray*)daysThisWeek
{
     return  [self daysInWeek:0 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
}

-(NSArray*)daysNextWeek
{
    return  [self daysInWeek:1 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
-(NSArray*)daysInWeek:(int)weekOffset fromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //ask for current week
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps=[calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    //create date on week start
    NSDate* weekstart=[calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSDateComponents* moveWeeks=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    moveWeeks.weekOfYear=weekOffset;            
    weekstart=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:moveWeeks toDate:weekstart options:0];


    //add 7 days
    NSMutableArray* week=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
    for (int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        NSDateComponents *compsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        compsToAdd.day=i;
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compsToAdd toDate:weekstart options:0];
        [week addObject:nextDate];

    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:week];
}
```

If you want to get dates of next to next week from today, then pass weekOffset=2 like this:-

```
NSArray * allDatesOfNextToNextWeek = [self daysInWeek:2 fromDate:now];
```

If you want to get dates of previous week from today, then pass weekOffset=-1 like this:-

```
NSArray * allDatesOfPreviousWeek = [self daysInWeek:-1 fromDate:now];
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me.

Answer (score 0):

`NSCalendar` contains dedicated methods to do that for example `nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options:` and `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`

```
// Get the current calendar
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
// Get the next occurrence for the first weekday of the current calendar
NSDate *startOfNextWeek = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:[NSDate date] matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday value:calendar.firstWeekday options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
// Create new date components +7 days and -1 seconds
NSDateComponents *endOfNextWeekComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
endOfNextWeekComponents.day = 7;
endOfNextWeekComponents.second = -1;
// Add the date components to the start date to get the end date.
NSDate *endOfNextWeek = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:endOfNextWeekComponents toDate:startOfNextWeek options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];

NSLog(@"%@ - %@", startOfNextWeek, endOfNextWeek);
```